# Is it possible to port Facebook iOS API to a normal OSX Desktop Application?

Tags: cocoa, facebook, ios

is it possible to port the Facebook iOS SDK (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) from github to a normal OSX Cocoa Application?
I'm a bit inexperienced in the way that I don't know what Projecttype they used for this SDK Project.

The Product is called "libfacebook_ios_sdk.a" and I really don't know what a "*.a" File is.
Can someone give me a hint which Project type I should use in XCode to port this iOS SDK?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, this is possible. And a .a file is a static library. See Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the SDK in the build settings, change the architecture, port the iOS-specific code (UI*) and build it. Then, go to your OSX app in Xcode and add the .a file as a framework.

If you want to copy the code into a new project instead, choose the Static Library template. You can also directly copy the code into your OSX app instead.